# Extracting placeholder from HTML tag using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am using the following python code to launch the Firefox webpage.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver= webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.quora.com")
```

After launching if somehow I know the xpath of this tag.

```
<input  
class="text header_login_text_box ignore_interaction" 
type="text" 
name="email" tabindex="1"
data-group="js-editable"
placeholder="Email"
w2cid="wZgD2YHa18" 
id="__w2_wZgD2YHa18_email">
```

I can extract attribute using selenium webdriver on python using the following command if I now the name of the attribute.

```
dict['attribute'] = driver.find_element_by_xpath(x_path).get_attribute(attribute)
```

so my output will be

```
dict = { 'attribute':value}
```

Please help me to figure out the way to extract all the attributes with its value even I don't known what are all the attributes it has. My expected output would be

```
dict = { "class" : "text header_login_text_box ignore_interaction" 
        "type" : "text" 
        "name":"email" 
         "tabindex" : "1"
        "data-group" : "js-editable"
        "placeholder" : "Email"
        "w2cid" : "wZgD2YHa18" 
        "id" : "__w2_wZgD2YHa18_email"
        }
```

I am not sure How far it is possible, but I am expecting like in dictionaries we can extract data even without knowing the keys.
Thank you

Comment: Show how you tried

Comment: Check added link

Comment: @KasiVisvanathan You shouldn't edit the question after you receive well researched canonical answers from the contributors. Else the existing answers will no longer remain valid and may not be useful to the future readers. If your requirement have changed feel free to raise a new question. StackOverflow contributors will be happy to help you out. I have reverted back the question to it's original state.

Answer (score 2):

To get `placeholder` attribute use `get_attribute()`

```
element.get_attribute('placeholder')
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the xpath of the input tag which you wish to extract the placeholder.

```
xpath_input = "//input[@id='__w2_wZgD2YHa18_email']"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_input)
```

After get the element, you can extract `placeholder` ("Email") by `get_attribute("placeholder")`

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_input).get_attribute("placeholder") This is working

Answer (score 0):

To extract the placeholder text i.e. **Email** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and then use `get_attribute()` method as follows:

- Line of Code:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='text header_login_text_box ignore_interaction' and @name='email']"))).get_attribute("placeholder"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Email
  ```
- Note : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```